# What is the best way to find all user facing text in an iOS app for localization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have an older objective-C iOS project with thousands of strings, both user facing and internal, that is not localized.

My main challenge is to identify user facing text that are string literals in code without NSLocalizedString wrapper.

I cannot just find and replace all string literals in code, as some (hundreds) of them are not user facing text.

Is there a way to find all the user facing strings, and wrap them with NSLocalizedString so that I can localize my app?

Comment: There is no "best way". You have to manually look at every string in the code and decide yourself whether to wrap it in `NSLocalizedString`. It's a terribly tedious process to go back and add localization to an old project. I went through that years ago on a very large code base. No fun. I now add the comment `// NO_I18N` to end of every line that contains a string that doesn't need to be localized. I wrote a script that scans source files for string literals and it filters out references to `NSLocalizedString` and the `NO_I18N` comment. What's left are strings that need to be localized.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to find an alternate to manually evaluating each string. That is the last resort!